# MacOS stopped generating crash reports

Tags: crash, ventura

I'm a software developer and I have an application (normally run from the terminal) that crashes from time to time (bus errors). It used to be that MacOS would generate a crash report, which was useful. However, starting this morning, the system no longer seems to generate crash reports, and I'm not sure why.

There is no crash report popup dialog any more. I also checked *Crash Reports* in the *Console* application but no new crash reports are appearing there.

I don't think I changed anything on the system.

Is there some reason for this, or some setting somewhere, or some other way I can re-enable crash reports?

MacOS Ventura 13.5, Apple M2 Pro

Comment: Check ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports .

Comment: Nothing there, but I got it worked out, kind of an obvious fix I guess, I'll post an answer.

Comment: @lhf Ventura is at 13.6.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I got it working again by simply rebooting the machine.

Kind of a silly fix, but I didn't think to do it right away since it's been ~201 days since the last time I had to reboot this machine.

I don't know what the root cause was, all I know is that rebooting fixed it.

I'll try updating to the latest Ventura and see if it ever happens again, maybe it's some issue that got fixed (I don't want to update past Ventura right now).